# Should I drill through the metal plate in my wall?

Tags: electrical, walls, drill, metal, curtain-rail

At home in my apartment, I was drilling into the top part of my wall to install a wall-mounted curtain rod.

I needed to mount it in 4 different areas of the wall, so I opted to install the first and last hooks first. These were installed with no issue. However as I marked out and started to drill into the wall to install hooks #2 and #3 in between, I hit something hard, which is very likely to be metal.

Normally this is a no brainer to stop drilling, but the placement is at the top of the wall, almost where it meets the ceiling. To me that would be an uncommon place for plumbing or electrical wires. Any guesses as to why there is metal plating at those specific spots on the wall (at #2 and #3, not #1 or #4)?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's an uncommon place for an electrical socket too. Just saying.

Comment: You have an outlet close by, to keep drilling is kind of stupid until you find the exact use of the metal.  It might be structural or protective of electric wires.  Your building management should have the building plans that should let you know what you are drilling into.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to know. There are about a hundred things that could be. What kind of wall framing do you have? It might just be a steel stud.

Comment: do you really want a guess? ... it makes no sense to spend time asking for a guess

Answer (score 3):

“Should I drill through a metal plate?”

No.

I suggest you reconsider the rail placements or cut a bunch of drywall and see what’s in there.

The alternative is possibly hitting power (there’s an outlet *right* there, as noted) and causing all kinds of troublesome repairs.